# Make the Alphabet enter capital if there is a space before it when entering text in the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the ALPHABET capitalize entered by the user in the textbox if there is a space before it.

Example user writes "test new" so "n" should be a capital and it will be so smooth that it feels like the user pressed the shift key

I think we can do the same in keydown event (jquery)

The code is something that i tried is:

```
$('.name').live("keydown", function (e) {
  try {
    if ($('.name').val().length > 1) {
      if ($('.name').val().substring($('.name').val().length - 1) == " ") {
        // HERE can we do something like e.shift key etc to get desired result
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you want to make it behave like the shift key, you'll have to examine the ASCII value, and subtract 32 or 16.

Comment: @Kamal Deep Singh: Yes observing ASCII Values should give you that ~chal saale :D (Utsav)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternative

```
​.name {
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: +1 nice catch ;)  (though the first char shouldn't be capitalized, I guess)

Comment: @AlexK. I cant believe it. You are genius, just a pure CSS

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$('#foo').on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).val(function (i, val) {
        return val.replace(/(\s)(\S)/g, function ($0, $1, $2) {
          return $1 + $2.toUpperCase();
        });
    });
});​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qPSpK/2/

Comment: good work but it is not smooth the user first saw the small letter which capitalized with delay. The user must saw capital letter directly which gives the feel as he.she pressed the caps key as this is the requirement

Comment: @KamalDeepSingh You can use the `input` event. Though you'll get problems with IE (<9) users.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised by the cleanliness of @AlexK's answer, but if you really need the first word lower-case (or just want some other form of seamless control of the text), try this jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("textarea").bind("keypress", function(e){              
        var cap = "";
        if(e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {
            cap = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toUpperCase();
        }
        if( cap != "" ) {
            var text = $(this).val();
            if( text[text.length-1] == " ") {
                $(this).val(text+cap);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });        
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkyYr/1/

Edit: changed switch statement to character mapping

Comment: Greattttttttttttt answer but still Alex K's answer is best.But still ur answer is very helpful for others